# Can I substitute movement for a Standard action?

Tags: movement, starfinder

I just joined a Starfinder campaign and have rolled up a solarian who will be joining the party in the next game. Since it’s been a while since I’ve played any 3e-derived games, I’ve been reviewing the tactical rules. I saw Withdraw as a full round action, but no general ability to use the standard action to move.

So if my solarian activates Dark Matter as a move action, he can still attack in that turn, but he would not be able to activate it and advance on an enemy. Is this correct? It seems odd from what I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starfinder allows actions to be 'downgraded' so a Standard action can be used as a Move action, and a Move action as a swift. Hence, you can use Dark Matter as a Move action, then take a second move action in place of your Standard action to move.

Source:

> You can use your standard action to perform either a move action or
>   a swift action, if you wish, and you can also use your move action to
>   perform a swift action.

Starfinder Core Rulebook, page 244

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, you can trade your standard action for another move action.

From the [SRD](http://www.starjammersrd.com/game-mastering/combat/#Action_Types):

> In a normal round, you can perform one standard action, one move action, and one swift action, or you can instead perform one full action. ... You can use your standard action to perform either a move action or a swift action, if you wish, and you can also use your move action to perform a swift action. ...

You can use your standard action to do anything that can be done with a move action, including moving around.